# Variant of in reference to

Tags: expressions, reading-comprehension

> Chinese officials and experts on Monday lambasted a G7 statement calling for ending import bans on Japanese food products, **in what Western media reports said is an apparent reference to** China's move after Japan's dumping of nuclear contaminated waste water into the sea, stating that the US LED group is the real perpetrator of economic coercion. https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202310/1300847.shtml

I figured this is adding some content to the fixed phrase "in reference to".  Is that normal or "play on words"？
I read several times before I understood this sentence, and I thought a set phrase cannot be broken into halves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the usage is somewhat different.

"In reference to," is a common phrase in business correspondence, e.g.,

This letter is in reference to an accident claim.

The "reference" points attention to a simple reason for that letter.

"An apparent reference to China's move..." is a little less direct. It expresses the belief that the Chinese officials were referring *indirectly* to U.S. coercion.